# SpecialCells(xlLastCell) doesn't update after deleting rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following vba code:

```
StartLastRow = .Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

If StartLastRow > 24 Then
    .Cells(StartLastRow, 1).CurrentRegion.EntireRow.Delete
    StartLastRow = .Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
End If
```

After deleting rows the value of `StartLastRow` remains the same.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Use `.Find`. See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

Comment: You could try adding: `Debug.print .UsedRange.Rows.Count` before resetting the variable.

Comment: saving workbook resets this, but as @SiddharthRout wrote, this is not the best way

Comment: @SiddharthRout I know that saving solves but I won't save while running the macro

Answer (score 1):

Following @Siddharth Rout comment above, using the `Find` function is the safest way to get the last row.

```
StartLastRow = FindLastRow

If StartLastRow > 24 Then
    .Cells(StartLastRow, 1).CurrentRegion.EntireRow.Delete
    StartLastRow = FindLastRow
End If

'=======================================================================

Function FindLastRow() As Long
    ' This Function finds the last row in a worksheet, and returns the row number
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Set LastCell = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not LastCell Is Nothing Then
        FindLastRow = LastCell.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "Error! worksheet is empty", vbCritical
        FindLastRow = -10000
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a workaround and I prefer to use another sheet (I can in this case). Anyway I appreciate (+1)